# Yom Kippur havdalah

Tags: yom-kippur, havdalah, smell

Why are there no besamim used at havdalah at the conclusion of Yom Kippur?

Comment: what about Y"K shechal b'shabbat?

Answer (score 6):

The Artscroll *machzor* says it's because we get no "extra soul" on *Yom Kipur* as we do on *Shabas*, so one doesn't need to *b'samim* to "assuage oneself" (their words) for the extra soul's loss when it leaves.

Comment: That's interesting considering the fact that the Rosh in arvei pesachim says that we do not use the besamim after yomtov because the extra soul does not leave after yomtov.

Comment: This is consistent with the idea that the "extra soul" is embodied in our ability to eat and enjoy more on שבת than on the other days.

Answer (score 4):

Tosfos in Pesachim asks why do we not use Besamim in Havdala which is recited in the Kiddush on Yom Tov which immediately follows Shabbos?

Rabbi Frand answers by quoting the Avnei Neizer who states that **there is** a Neshoma Yiseira on Yom Tov and therefore we do not smell Besamim in Havdala after Yom Tov? Since the Neshama Yiseira does not depart after Yom Tov, therefore there is no need for the Besamim. Unlike the Neshama Yiseira which comes on Shabbos without work on our part, the extra Kedusha on Yom Tov requires that we work to prepare for it. Since we have earned this Kedusha, it does not depart when Yom Tov ends.

Comment: See my comment below Shalom's answer. Maybe, you have an idea?

Answer (score 4):

Rashi says the Neshama Yeseira is so we can eat more.  On Yom Kippur we don't eat!  (But according to Rashi, what about other yomtov ...)

Comment: Where does Rash"i say this? I could use that ref. as support when my wife warns me not to eat stuff on Shabbat b/c I'll get fat. (I'm fat, already!)